# Can YOU discover the word?

Tags: riddle, word

> Over time I am worn and worn away like anything else
>
> A close cousin of mine treks through desert though I prefer the forest
>
> Double the third and remove the first and I become a little bit
>   explosive
>
> Remove the last and you may see yourself in me someday

**What am I?**

This has gone through the [sandbox](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/the-riddle-sandbox).

Comment: Love. The word is love.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you

> camo (as in, camouflage)?

Over time I am worn and worn away like anything else

> Camo is certainly worn, as clothing; not sure about being worn away.

A close cousin of mine treks through desert though I prefer the forest

> Cam*el* (close in spelling/pronunciation), a desert dweller. Camo is commonly seen with the dark green/forest color scheme, though 'desert' and 'urban' camo schemes are also used.

Double the third and remove the first and I become a little bit explosive

> CAMO -> AMMO.

Remove the last and you may see yourself in me someday

> CAMO -> CAM. I can see myself when i look at recordings from my web*cam*.

Comment: +1 I was thinking of just that, you beat me to interpreting the clues.

Comment: Worn away = worn away from home?

Comment: When I read "Worn away" I think more in terms of eroding.

Comment: Great answer! Love this site and you guys as well.

Comment: Worn away – maybe because the US military is phasing out blue camouflage in their uniforms? Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

> carbon dioxide

The first clue:

> CO2 sequestration into its unattached constituents occurs slowly over time

Second:

> Methane is produced by camels; forests use CO2 for photosynthesis

Third:

> Remove carbon and double the second oxygen, and you get O3 -- ozone -- a potent oxidative accelerant

Fourth:

> Carbon monoxide -- CO -- is deadly, and is used as a meat preservative because of the very trait that renders it lethal -- it strongly attaches to hemoglobin, making it unable to accept or release oxygen ...

Comment: How is CO2 a close cousin of camels?